# Generate Entities from an Existing Database

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony and now I am currently doing an application using this framework. I am now trying to [generate entities from an existing database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) and while I run the following command:

```
php app\console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation .\src\AppBundle\Resources\config\doctrine
```

I've got this error message:

> No Metadata Classes to process.

Could you please tell me what's happening with this?

Comment: before annotation command you have to run `php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle xml` so it will generate meta classes

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I'm already done with that part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs, it seems you are missing the --from-database argument. I've never used that tool though.

http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
```

Comment: I already did the one you suggested and it succeeded but when I did the next step I encountered another error: `Namespace "AppBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\.." does not contain any mapped entities.`

Comment: `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle` then I also tried `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\` but still receive the same error.

Comment: You need to use php app/console doctrine:generate:entity (not plural) to generate a new entity. Plural is to modify an existing entity.

Comment: If you have a User table, then you should now have a User entity. Type in php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:User to modify it

Comment: nah, it's not working but I found a solution I typed in `php app/console doctrine:generate:entity` then it finally worked. thanks for sparing me some of your time sir. it really helped me A LOT. :)